# How to store values in 3D array based on different input

Tags: python

I want to store the values in an array based on each n, dx, and dt respectively. So later I can load or call sepreatly. I git this error.
**IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 100**
Do any suggestions, please?

```
L=20
K=100
x=np.arange(0,L,1)
t=np.arange(1,K+1)
d=np.zeros((K,len(x),len(t))) #makes an empty array

#use loop
for n in np.arange(1,K+1):
wn=n*math.pi*v/L
F=math.exp(-wn*0.2)**2/4
for dx in x:
    for dt in t:
        d[n,dx,dt]=math.sin(n*math.pi*xs/L)*F*math.sin(wn*dx/v)*math.cos(wn*dt)
```

It's a bit simple in Matlab but I don't know how can I do it in python?

```
**L=20;
  c=3;
  xs=8;
  k=100;
  x=0:0.01:L;
  t=1:100;
  tau=1;
  for n=1:k
  wn=n*pi*c/L;
  F=exp(-(wn*tau)^2/4);
  mode_nxt(n,:,:)=sin(n*pi*xs/L)*F*sin(wn*x/c)'*cos(wn*t);
  end**
```

Comment: In python, indexing starts from 0, not from 1. To access the nth element, the syntax is array[n-1]. In your t loop, t starts from 1 and goes to 100, d[n,dx,100] imples you are accessing the 101 in the 3rd dimension which is out of bound as your array can accommodate 100 elements in 3rd dimension. replace d[n,dx,dt] with d[n,dx,dt-1] to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the comment. **d[n,dx,dt-1]=math.sin(n*math.pi*xs/L)*F*math.sin(wn*dx/v)*math.cos(wn*dt)** I tried this way but get the error : IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Let me modify it. thanks

Comment: @Murali may i ask why i get this error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices, when I use **d[n,dx,dt]=math.sin(n*math.pi*xs/L)*F*math.sin(wn*dx/v)*math.cos(wn*dt)**. but it works well if I used integars such as I, J in loop

Comment: Please edit the question with the code you have currently and error. From the error message, I think you are trying to give floats for index values.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing in python starts from 0 so for an array of size 100 the indexes would be 0-99. 100 would be out of bounds. Your loop should be.

```
for n in np.arange(1,K):
```